# Is there way to use assertion in cycle to find all broken images on page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using `selenium webdriver` + `TestNG`. Help me to solve following issue if possible:

Searching all broken images on page and show them (using assertion) in console after test fails.

The following test fails after first broken image is found, I need test to check all images and show result when it fails:

```
public class BrokenImagesTest3_ {

@Test
public static void links() throws IOException, StaleElementReferenceException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/C: ...");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://some url");

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //Find total Number of links on page and print In console.
    List<WebElement> total_images  = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
    System.out.println("Total Number of images found on page = " + total_images .size());

    //for loop to open all links one by one to check response code.
    boolean isValid = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < total_images .size(); i++) {
        String image = total_images .get(i).getAttribute("src");


        if (image != null) {

            //Call getResponseCode function for each URL to check response code.
            isValid = getResponseCode(image);

            //Print message based on value of isValid which Is returned by getResponseCode function.
            if (isValid) {
                System.out.println("Valid image:" + image);
                System.out.println("----------XXXX-----------XXXX----------XXXX-----------XXXX----------");
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Broken image ------> " + image);
                System.out.println("----------XXXX-----------XXXX----------XXXX-----------XXXX----------");
                System.out.println();
            }
        } else {
            //If <a> tag do not contain href attribute and value then print this message
            System.out.println("String null");
            System.out.println("----------XXXX-----------XXXX----------XXXX-----------XXXX----------");
            System.out.println();
            continue;
        }

    }
    driver.close();
}

//Function to get response code of link URL.
//Link URL Is valid If found response code = 200.
//Link URL Is Invalid If found response code = 404 or 505.
public static boolean getResponseCode(String chkurl) {
    boolean validResponse = false;
    try {
        //Get response code of image
        HttpClient client  = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(chkurl);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        int resp_Code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println(resp_Code);
        Assert.assertEquals(resp_Code, 200);
        if (resp_Code != 200)  {
            validResponse = false;
        } else {
            validResponse = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return validResponse;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code stops at the first failure is because you are using an `Assert` for the `resp_Code` to equal 200. TestNG will stop execution on the first failed assert.

I would do this a little differently. You can use a CSS selector to find only images that contain a `src` attribute using `"img[src]"` so you don't have to deal with that case. When I look for broken images, I use the `naturalWidth` attribute. It will be 0 if the image is broken. Using these two pieces, the code would look like...

```
List<WebElement> images = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("img[src]"));
System.out.println("Total Number of images found on page = " + images.size());
int brokenImagesCount = 0;
for (WebElement image : images)
{
    if (isImageBroken(image))
    {
        brokenImagesCount++;
        System.out.println(image.getAttribute("outerHTML"));
    }
}
System.out.println("Count of broken images: " + brokenImagesCount);
Assert.assertEquals(brokenImagesCount, 0, "Count of broken images is 0");
```

then add this function

```
public boolean isImageBroken(WebElement image)
{
    return !image.getAttribute("naturalWidth").equals("0");
}
```

I'm only writing out the images that are broken. I prefer this method since it keeps the log cleaner. Writing `image` is going to write gibberish that isn't going to be useful so I changed that to write the outerHTML which is the HTML of the IMG tag.

Comment: In such cases, I often append the src attributes of the invalid images to a string builder and assert that its length is zero, using the content of the builder as part of the message. That way you do get something more specific in the log.

Comment: You are likely to get a stale element, if you loop through a list of `WebElement`s like this.

Comment: @PeteKirkham These invalid images won't contain an empty src. The CSS selector filters them out. These are more around images that don't exist or bad URLs. Any that fail will have their full HTML of the IMG tag logged anyway.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz I'm not sure why you think that. Stale elements occur when you trigger a dynamic change to the page or change pages. Looping through a list of elements and checking the naturalWidth won't do either.

Comment: Thank you guys, you helped me a lot!

Comment: @KoliaKulka You're welcome. If this answer (or any answer) was helpful, please upvote it. If it answered your question, please accept it so the question gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

`assertEquals()` is throwing `AssertionError`, not an `Exception`. If codes are not equal in your case it will throw `AssertionError` and your test will stop and finish as failed.
If you catch `Error` instead of `Exception` in your `catch()` it should probably work as you expect it.

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to JeffC's, I prefer to collect the erroneous src attributes and report them as the failure rather than logging to a separate file, something like:

```
List<WebElement> images = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("img[src]"));
System.out.println("Total Number of images found on page = " + images.size());
StringBuilder brokenImages = new StringBuilder();
for (WebElement image : images)
    if (isImageBroken(image))
        brokenImages.append(image.getAttribute("src")).append(";");
Assert.assertEquals(brokenImages.getLength(), 0,
    "the following images failed to load", brokenImages);
```

(only an answer as it's easier to explain with code than in a comment)